# Replace special characters in hive columns

Tags: mysql, hive, special-characters

I have a table in mysql say emp

The column names are emp.id, emp.name, emp.salary, emp.dno

Now I do sqoop import and create a hive table emp in single statement.

when I query the hive table emp using select * query

I get the error

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: RuntimeException java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find field emp from [0:emp.id, 1:emp.name, 2:emp.salary, 3:emp.dno]
```

As hive doesn't support special characters How can I fix this.

Can we replace the .(dot) with _(underscore) as hive supports underscores in column name.

If Yes, then how can we do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing column name in hive once the sqoop import is finished

```
ALTER TABLE EMP
CHANGE `emp.id` emp_id int
```

Comment: I did that but I want to do that dynamically while creating the hive table itself

Comment: you can use sqoop's `--query` option to change coulmn name while importing.

like 
`
    Sqoop import 
    --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db --username retail_dba 
    --password cloudera  
    --e 'SELECT `order.id` AS ORDER_ID FROM orderdot where    $CONDITIONS ' 
    --hive-import 
    --m 1 
    --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/orderdot 
    --hive-table orderdot
`

Comment: I have more than 50 columns like the above problem how can we pass the select argument dynamically @Pushkr